# How to make an HTML GUI for PowerShell scripts?

Tags: html, powershell, frontend

I have an automation script for making new AD clients and Google mails.
I would like to make a Web UI for this (HTML & CSS) so my team can log to this page and create from anywhere thy are.

How can I do it?

Is there a guide for making an HTML page connected to the PowerShell script?

Comment: Pick a server side scripting language of your choice. They all support some sort of `exec()` command to execute scripts on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

One option (of many) is to have Powershell host your HTML.  Use the **System.Net.HttpListener** web listener, and answers requests based on what you are wanting to provide.

There is an article about building a web server with Powershell:
https://4sysops.com/archives/building-a-web-server-with-powershell/
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/HttpListener/1.0.2/Content/HTTPListener.psm1

When you have such low level control of the data scream, you can leverage the power of HTML into powershell.

Now, while this fits your question, this is pretty complicated (any time you have to develop in multiple languages at the same time --  HTML, Powershell, perhaps Javascript, etc), it can get complex in a hurry.

My suggestion is to make sure you really need the app your building to be web based.

If you just wanting GUI (and web is not a requirement) then this task would be far easier using the .NET forms ability of some of the other answers.

The powershell gallery link actually has a functional Powershell web server script in just under 175 lines (plus comments) that was originally written within Microsoft in 2014.

(The Microsoft code, in case it moves URL's, is called HTTPListener.psm1 so it can be found in a web engine search)

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug, but I've recently published a .NET5-based open source web app you might want to check out called [SpecOps](https://github.com/KennethScott/SpecOps).   It's intended to allow non-technical users the ability to run powershell scripts via a web-based GUI.  You define your scripts and their input parameters in a json config file and it builds the GUI for your users on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You use HTML GUIs ([HTA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) for VBScript and/or JavaScript. For PowerShell you use [Windows Forms](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stephap/archive/2012/04/23/building-forms-with-powershell-part-1-the-form.aspx).

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms | Out-Null

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.AutoSize = $true
$form.AutoSizeMode = 'GrowAndShrink'

$form.Text = 'Window Title'

$label = New-Object Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Text = 'some text'
$label.AutoSize = $true
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: This would only work after invoking the script. Not as an interface to invoke the scripts in the first place.

Comment: True, but inconsequential. You can easily build authentication into the script, and make it available via a common share.

Comment: The question was how to use Powershell as a backend for a web client.  What is shown here is how to make a Powershell GUI.  This misses the biggest point of the request, that of being HTML based.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeD. There is no need for using HTML when you're making a GUI for PowerShell scripts because the GUI can be embedded in the script. That way it can be run on any administrative client rather than having to set up web server running a web GUI that in turn runs a PowerShell script.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers -- Again, you've missed the question is my point.  The question was not "How to make a GUI for PowerShell scripts?".  It was "How to make an HTML GUI for PowerShell scripts?".
We don't know what possible limits the OP who asked the question has.  It may be, for some reason, it has to be in HTML (maybe it's part of an existing web site).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeD. Your point is moot b/c while the OP is *asking* for a HTML GUI they don't -as you stated yourself- provide enough information about the environment in which they intend to run it. Given their reputation and the overall quality of the question this might very well be an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). My answer provides a perfectly valid (and in fact the preferred) way of creating GUIs for PowerShell scripts.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers  I made no reference to your answering being invalid as a GUI solution, and I don't question that the question could be better.  However, given the limited info of the ask, would it not be best to have the solution presented at least fit within that information?
I mean, had they asked for a solution in Powershell and you provided a perfect answer, but in C#, would you not agree that the answer misses the question?
Maybe we need to agree to disagree on this one.
I'd have suggested having Powershell as a backend to IIS, or using using System.Net.HttpListener within PS.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeD. *"given the limited info of the ask, would it not be best to have the solution presented at least fit within that information?"* No, it wouldn't, b/c that would be an inferior solution. I posted what from my understanding is the best solution for the problem the OP described. You're free to disagree. But suggesting to run a webserver for this with all the inherent security implications just to meet the HTML requirement (which may very well not actually be a requirement in the first place) is just ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest might be to use a package like Jenkins that supplies a front end and has auth plugins already and can run powershell as well.

https://jenkins-ci.org/

There is a plugin for running powershell.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PowerShell+Plugin

You can even tie it to Active Directory if you need.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Directory+plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically generate a web front-end for PowerShell scripts using [System Frontier](http://systemfrontier.com/powershell). No HTML or server-side programming needed. You just create custom fields and assign them to command-line parameters.

You also get the benefits of having an access control layer in front of the scripts so non-admins can safely run the scripts *with* admin rights. The script output is also logged for auditing and data mining.